# How to get access to the current request and route in Flask and check if it's ajax or not?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have the following route:

```
@app.route("/my_page")
@app.route("/my_page.json")
def targets():

  # .....
```

I want to return an html template if it's a simple http request, and json if it's an ajax request and the route ends with ".json". How can I determine that? I've tried accessing "request" but it was none.

```
*** NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [in the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object), you need to import the request before you can use it.

```
from flask import request

...
def targets():
    if request.is_xhr():
        ...
```